# BASH Syntax Error - [: missing `]'

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am new to Bash programming and probably being really silly.

Basically I am writing a piece of script that will ping an IP Address I pass in, it will take from it packets transmitted and return an error or a pass message depending on the number of packets lost.

However whenever I run the script from my terminal I keep getting message -

`./ipGatewayCheck.sh: line 13: [: missing`]'`

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

healthy_status=0

warning_status=10

critical_status=100

for gateway in $@

do
RESULT=`ping -q -c 10 $gateway | grep 'packets transmitted' | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d "%"`
echo "$RESULT"
if [ $RESULT -eq $healthy_status ]; then
  echo "No Issue - IP Address is pinging"
elif [ $RESULT -ge $warning_status && -le $critical_status ]; then
  echo "Warning - Issue with packet loss on this IP Address"
elif [ $RESULT -eq $critical_status ]; then
  echo "Critical - 100% packet loss on this IP Address"
fi

done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$RESULT -ge $warning_status && -le $critical_status` is interpreted as `($RESULT -ge $warning_status) && (-le $critical_status)` and the second part means nothing... Not sure this is you problem but this is a problem. Furthermore, I'm not sure that your conditions should end with semicolumns but I can't test it now

Comment: Thanks everyone! It seemed to work fine! With Anubhava's method!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `[[` and `]]` in order to use `&&` inside square brackets:

```
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "$healthy_status" ]]; then
  echo "No Issue - IP Address is pinging"
elif [[ "$RESULT" -ge "$warning_status" && "$RESULT" -le "$critical_status" ]]; then
  echo "Warning - Issue with packet loss on this IP Address"
elif [[ "$RESULT" -eq "$critical_status" ]]; then
  echo "Critical - 100% packet loss on this IP Address"
fi
```

Alternatively you can also use `((` and `))` in BASH:

```
if (( RESULT == healthy_status )); then
  echo "No Issue - IP Address is pinging"
elif (( RESULT == warning_status && RESULT < critical_status )); then
  echo "Warning - Issue with packet loss on this IP Address"
elif (( RESULT == critical_status )); then
  echo "Critical - 100% packet loss on this IP Address"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

As diagnosed by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991334/15168), the problem is that the `&&` operator terminates the test command leaving you with a `[` without a matching `]` and the error message you get.

There's an alternative fix — more traditional shell coding and portable to shells other than Bash.
If you wish to use `[`, you have to use either the `-a` conjunction (instead of `&&`), or use two separate tests:

```
elif [ "$RESULT" -ge $warning_status -a "$RESULT" -le "$critical_status" ]; then

elif [ "$RESULT" -ge $warning_status ] && [ "$RESULT" -le "$critical_status" ]; then
```

Note that I had to add the second `"$RESULT"`; I also enclosed the variables inside double quotes to make sure there are no mishaps.

Comment: Note that the POSIX standard considers the XSI extension `-a` obsolete, and recommends using two tests joined by `&&` instead.